# How to know what roles or permissions are allowed to push code/PR to production using Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, git-branch

I need to get from the Azure Devops list of a users who are allowed to push code/PR to master/main branch. This list should be foreach repo seperatly.

But, after searching Rest Api doct for Azure, haven't found nothig.
[image: That's the data i need toget]

I tried using Inspector see what request get's this data
`https://dev.azure.com/something/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery`
That's Hidden Api and this won't work for me.